# Can't retrieve object from user cache Google Apps Script

Tags: caching, google-apps-script, web-applications

I am having a problem retrieving an object from the user cache in Google Apps Script. I don't get null, I just get an empty object. I'm even wondering if the object is being saved properly into the user cache. Any help is really appreciated. Here is what I have so far...

This codes does NOT work:

```
// global variable to access user cache
var cache = CacheService.getUserCache();

// the function to save to cache for an end-user
function saveToUserCache(dynamicObj) {
  Logger.log(dynamicObj); // the object displays here
  cache.putAll(dynamicObj, 300);
  Logger.log(cache.getAll(['test1', 'test2'])); // the object does not display here
}
```

This is called from the .html file:

```
...
// Object being passed dynamically: 
var testObj = {'test1': "value1",'test2': "value2"};
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).saveToUserCache(testObj);
...
```

This code works:

```
// global variable to access user cache
var cache = CacheService.getUserCache();

// object to pass into the function
var testObj = {'test1': "value1",'test2': "value2"};

// the function to save to cache for an end-user
function saveToUserCache() {
  Logger.log(testObj); // the object displays here
  cache.putAll(testObj, 300);
  Logger.log(cache.getAll(['test1', 'test2'])); // the object displays here
}
```

To give some context... The reason I need to use the first block of code is because I am passing an object from the front-end GUI using `withSuccessHandler()`. And as you can see the object displays fine in the the fist Logger, so the data gets to the `saveToUserCache()` function, but after that, I can't retrieve it from the cache in the first block of code. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190053/discussion-on-question-by-alex-cant-retrieve-object-from-user-cache-google-apps).

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce your issue with the following client & server code:

#### code.gs (server side)

```
function saveToUserCache(clientObject) {
  const cache = CacheService.getUserCache();
  const clientKeys = Object.keys(clientObject);

  console.log({message: "object from client code", clientObject: clientObject, user: Session.getTemporaryActiveUserKey()});
  cache.putAll(clientObject, 300);
  const values = cache.getAll(clientKeys);
  console.log({message: "Retrieved key values from client object", keys: clientKeys, values: values});
  return {"type": "user", values: values};
}

var testObject = {"script_test1": "script_value1", "script_test2": "script_value2"};
function saveNonParameterToUserCache() {
  const cache = CacheService.getUserCache();
  const scriptKeys = Object.keys(testObject);

  console.log({message: "global var object", testObject: testObject, user: Session.getTemporaryActiveUserKey()});
  cache.putAll(testObject, 300);
  const values = cache.getAll(scriptKeys);
  console.log({message: "Retrieved key values from test object", keys: scriptKeys, values: values});
  return {"type":"fixed", values: values};
}

function showSidebar() {
  const output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("usercachetest.html");
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(output);
}
```

#### usercachetest.html (client side)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="doit()">Click to run</button>
  </body>
  <script>
    function doit() {
      console.log("running doit");
      var clientObject = {"user_test1": "user_value1", "user_test2": "user_value2"};
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).saveToUserCache(clientObject);
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).saveNonParameterToUserCache();
    }
    function onSuccess(result) {
      console.log(result);
    }
    </script>
</html>
```

Run the `showSidebar` function, switch to the Google Sheets container file, and then open the browser console. Click the sidebar button. Check your Stackdriver logs -- everything seems great.

[image]

Note that per the limitations of `CacheService`, all keys and all values placed into a [`Cache`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache#put(String,String)) must be string. A good practice is to use `JSON.stringify` on the values before caching them, and then `JSON.parse`ing the retrieved items (if any) from the cache before returning them for consumption. For example:

```
function foo(inputObject) {
  if (!inputObject) return;
  const cacheable = Object.keys(inputObject).reduce(function (obj, key) {
    obj[key] = JSON.stringify(inputObject[key]);
    return obj;
  }, {});
  CacheService.get____Cache().putAll(cacheable, expiryTime);
  ...
}
```

Take special care also that you do not pass [invalid types from client to server](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#parameters_and_return_values) - things like `Date` objects are not allowed, and will result in an undefined / missing function parameter.

Comment: sigh... and you post this right after I said it.... It still doesn't explain how the object passes on the first part of my code that doesn't work, under the first Logger.log. And on top of that you started the previous conversation by saying that the syntax was wrong. Now, you just repeated what I said and posted it as an answer.

Comment: @alex In fairness, my first comment, now deleted, was meant to point out that you cannot pass object *values* to be cached, i.e. `{"key1": { "subkey1": "value1" }}`. To cache object *values*, you must stringify them first: `{"key1": "{\"subkey1\": \"value1\"}"}`, and then parse it after retrieval.  w.r.t why your first logger works and the second fails, but not reproducibly, i can only suggest that the implementation of `CacheService` is probably asynchronous in some aspects and thus there was a delay in writing the keys. A read from `Cache` may be synchronous - only a Googler could say.

Comment: Also when testing key retrieval, make sure the keys tested are different each and every time, lest you read in one test the keys put there in an earlier test.